# Ionic Android broadcast event from javascript to native

Tags: broadcastreceiver, ionic4

I am trying to send an event from javascript (angular to be specific) to android via the broadcaster plugin : https://github.com/bsorrentino/cordova-broadcaster

In the UI i fire a native event with some data:

```
this.broadCaster
    .fireNativeEvent("com.service.print", { extras: { item: "test data" } })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("broadcast sent:" + result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending broadcast:" + error);
    });
```

On the android i registered a receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name="io.ionic.starter.PrintReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.service.print"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And added the `PrintReceiver` class to handle the `broadcast`:

```
public class PrintReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String data = intent.getExtras().getString("data");
    List<PrinterCommand> commands = new ArrayList<PrinterCommand>();

    // Add commands to be sent
    commands.add(
      new PrinterCommand(PrinterCommand.CommandType.TEXT, "Normal row 1\n")
    );
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(commands);
    System.out.println("Sending print broadcast: " + json);
    Intent printIntent = new Intent(MyPOSUtil.PRINT_BROADCAST);

    // Add the commands
    printIntent.putExtra("commands", json);

    // Send broadcast
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcastSync(printIntent);
  }
}
```

When i am trying to run the app on Android device i get this error:

```
2020-07-31 10:31:34.007 11308-11416/io.ionic.starter V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: broadcaster343151718, service: broadcaster, action: fireNativeEvent, actionArgs: ["com.service.print",{"extras":{"item":"test data"}},false]
2020-07-31 10:31:34.022 11308-11433/io.ionic.starter V/CDVBroadcaster: sendBroadcast isGlobal=false
2020-07-31 10:31:34.051 11308-11308/io.ionic.starter I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/auth-auth-module-es2015.js - Line 70 - Msg: Error sending broadcast:OK
```

Note: i tried using the same plugin to receive a broadcast from android and it works.

What could be the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Eventually i figured out that there was nothing wrong with the brodcaster plugin and that it actually sends a correct broadcast.

What i learnt is that as of Android 8 you cannot register your receiver in the Manifest.xml, but use context based registration.

[Android 8+ manifest registration restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)